# Ember.js - Wrong URL request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am try make ember-rails works for me, but a bizarre error happens. I have a model Client, and my routes are:

```
App.Router.map () ->
   @resources('clients')
```

and

```
App.ClientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
      @get('store').findAll 'client'
```

But, the request point to:  http://my.app:3000/api/v1/lients.

I really dont know why this happen. Note 'lients' instead of 'clients'.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [emberscript](http://emberscript.com/)?

Comment: No, i am not using emberscript

Comment: will you please show your client model, and your adapter and serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Client Model

```
App.Client = DS.Model.extend
   name: DS.attr('string')
```

Adapter

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen namespace: "api/v1"
App.Store = DS.Store.extend(
  revision: 11
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create()
)
```

Serializer

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```